# how to write unit test for service using $q and $http function in karma?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

```
angular.module('test').service('TestServices', TestServices);
  TestServices.inject = ['$window ', '$http', ' $q'];
  function TestServices($window, $http, $q) {
  var _this = this;
  _this.getData = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var url = '/test/url';
      //http call
      $http({ 
      method: 'GET',
      url: url 
      }).then(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }, function(response) {
            deferred.reject(response);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
}
```

Above given is my service function, i need to write unit test for service in karma. currently using angular 1.6 version. can any one know how to write the unit test???

Comment: What you are looking for is [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend).

Comment: $httpBackend.whenGET('/test/url').respond(200, {data : 'test'});
       service.getData();
       $httpBackend.flush(); i used above function inside it block which cover the test part but i need to resolve with $q

Answer (score 0):

use $rootScope.$apply() it will resolve all the promises.

Comment: can you give the code for resolve data in service test file using $q

Comment: use it before $httpBackend.flush();